# Why doesn't this .slice method work? Working in Eloquent Javascript, Chapter 4

Tags: javascript, function, return, slice, reverse

Trying a tutorial from Eloquent Javascript, creating a function that Reverses Array In Place (i.e. without storing value in a new array). I have since solved using other methods, but still don't understand why my slicing doesn't seem to work.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  let count = 0;
  
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    array.push(array[i]);
    count++
  }
  
  return array.slice(count)
}

console.log(reverseArrayInPlace(["a", "b", "c"]))
```

I don't understand why I can't successfully return the array sliced as the final step - instead it's returning the entire array [

This push method successfully added the values in the reverse order - and the count variable successfully tracks the index where the slice would need to take place.  I would like to have the final action of function slice the array and store is as this newly sliced array.

Not interested in other methods to solve - interested why this slicing won't work, please!

Comment: Your snippet works for me, it returns `["c", "b", "a"]`

Comment: You don't need to calculate `count`, just use `let count = array.length;`

Comment: A side note: `slice` creates a new array and doesn't modify the original array. So it's not applicable to reversing "in place".

Comment: This is not actually reversing in place. It adds the reversed elements to the end of the original array, but `slice()` creates a new array to hold the slice, it doesn't modify the original array.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't reversing in place. It appends the reversed elements to the end of the original array, then returns a new array containing that slice. If you log the original array, you'll see both the original and reversed contents.

You can use `splice()` to remove the original elements, then return the updated array.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  let count = array.length;
  
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    array.push(array[i]);
  }
  array.splice(0, count); // remove the original elements
  return array;
}

let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(reverseArrayInPlace(a));
console.log(a);
```